# Colab GPU session disconnects within 10-15 mins

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, carla

I'm trying to run this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/MichaelBosello/carla-colab/blob/master/carla-simulator.ipynb) which causes GPU session to disconnect within 10-15 minutes. I tried with different accounts, and I get the same results. If I try to reconnect, I get `You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Colab` despite not even using the GPU (the notebook never makes it past initial installations).

Comment: Does the error persist if you subscribe to [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup)?

Comment: If someone has a subscription, please let us know